# pygame.KEYDOWN missing inputs

Tags: python, input, keydown

So I'm making a guitar hero like game in python 3.6.0. I'm trying to use pygame.KEYDOWN to check when the space bar it tapped. However I'm finding that sometimes it is missing some inputs and not increasing my hit count. Here is the relevant part of code:

```
import pygame as pyg
pyg.init()


hit=0


pyg.key.set_repeat()


playFlag=True

while playFlag:

    pyg.event.get()
    redraw_screen()
    for event in pyg.event.get():    
    if event.type == pyg.QUIT:       
        playFlag = False                


    if event.type==pyg.KEYDOWN and event.key==pyg.K_SPACE:

     for i in range(len(song1)):
         if 550>noteheight[i]>450:
            hit+=1
              noteheight[i]=700

#Moves the notes
for i in range(len(song1)):
    noteheight[i]+=notespeed

pyg.time.delay(10)
```

pyg.quit()

Comment: We'll need to see more of your code...  Ideally you'd provide a minimal example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I added a little bit more code to show how the main body works. If you wan't me to go ahead and add the function I have to redraw the window and all the global variable then I can do that as well, I just don't want to make the  code too hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can find as to why your hit counter may not be working is you most likely have it declared within the loop which this code is written, therefore resetting it every interval. As far as missing notes go, I can't really help you... I'm not sure what you're really trying to do here. Your 3rd line specifically.